# Use symbolic link in vhost file

Tags: apache

I am running my server and I am using vhost file. I want to use symbolic link in the `DocumentRoot` parameter. Take a look:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@localhost.com
DocumentRoot "/www/html/example"
ServerName example.com
ErrorLog "logs/example"
CustomLog "logs/example" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a symbolic link set from /var/apache/www -> /ebs1/apache/www

How can I make it work? Apache is not following the symbolic link!

Answer (score 4):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/apache/www
    ServerName example.com 
    <Directory  /var/apache/www>
        Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Comment: `FollowSymlinks` --> `FollowSymLinks` (uppercase `L`)